# Get the "absolute" URL of a state in Angular-UI?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular and Angular-UI [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).  I have some states defined:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider
    .state('tabs', {
        url: "/tab",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "views/tabs.html"
    })
    .state('tabs.home', {
        url: "/home",
        views: {
            'home-tab': {
                templateUrl: "views/home.html"
            }
        }
    });
```

Note that I am using abstract states.  Is there a handy function that gets me the URL of a given state by name?  For example I want something like:

```
$state.get('tabs.home').absoluteUrl
```

which should return a value like `#/tab/home`.

Comment: Why do you need it? What would you expect to happen if you have variables in your routes (eg: `/home/:someVar`)?

Comment: I just want to reference the URL's in some places by state name rather than hard-coding the URL's everywhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are searching for is a built in `$state` method `href()`. You can see an [example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ASk1m1?p=preview). The documentation:

- [href(stateOrName, params, options)](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.%24state)

How to get the current state href?

> **`$state.href($state.current.name);`**

Let's have this extended mapping *(see detailed definition in the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ASk1m1?p=preview))*:

```
$stateProvider.
        state('tabs', {
            url: '/tab',
            abstract: true,...
        })
        .state('tabs.home', {
            url: '/home',...
        })
        .state('tabs.home.detail', {
            url: '/{id:[0-9]{1,4}}',...
        })
        .state('tabs.home.detail.edit', {
            url: '^/edit/{id:[0-9]{1,4}}',...
        });
```

The example of state calls:

```
ui-sref
<ul>
  <li><a ui-sref="tabs.home">Tabs/Home</a></li>
  <li><a ui-sref="tabs.home.detail({id:4})">Tabs/Home id 4</a></li>
  <li><a ui-sref="tabs.home.detail({id:5})">Tabs/Home id 5</a></li>
  <li><a ui-sref="tabs.home.detail.edit({id:4})">Tabs/Home id 4 - edit</a></li>
  <li><a ui-sref="tabs.home.detail.edit({id:5})">Tabs/Home id 5 - edit</a></li>
</ul>
href 
<ul>
  <li><a href="#/tab/home">Tabs/Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#/tab/home/4">Tabs/Home id 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#/tab/home/5">Tabs/Home id 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#/edit/4">Tabs/Home id 4 - edit</a></li>
  <li><a href="#/edit/5">Tabs/Home id 5 - edit</a></li>
</ul>
```

And in each of them we can call

> `var href =` **`$state.href($state.current.name);`**

which will result in the

```
#/tab/home
#/tab/home/4
#/tab/home/5
#/edit/5 -- this state resets the url form the root 
#/edit/5 -- see the (^) at the start of the url definition
```

Comment: Great if that helped ;) enjoy the awesome `ui-router`